Water System Modeling: Snap Line-to-Point, or Line-to-Line?
I would like work on setting-up our water distribution system in a way that will allow for the utilization of water modeling, i.e., leak detection. I believe that in order to do this, certain rules need to be in place. For example, when service lines/ mains are created, draw in the direction of water flow. I was also always told that lines need to be connected via a point. Recently, however, someone said that lines need to connect directly to other lines. Which is correct, or does it not matter? Are there any resources out there, aside from stack exchange that could help clarify these questions? I've tried to research various things over the years, but have yet to find anything all that helpful.

Network made from edges and nodes., so - points. Even in absence of physical 'point'. There is connection to edge, but I think it is bad idea.

Sounds like you would benefit from training on the specifics of setting up and using a utility network. ESRI provide self lead training in this subject here.
